# Как исправить ошибку "session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter"?

Tags: opencart

Здравствуйте использую Import модуль для OpenCart, хотел импортировать файл YML, как вдруг перед импортом вылазит вот такая ошибка:

**Warning: POST Content-Length of 427892364 bytes exceeds the limit of 104857600 bytes in Unknown on line 0
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent in C:\OpenServer\domains\alfamega\system\library\session.php on line 21Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in C:\OpenServer\domains\alfamega\system\library\response.php on line 12**

Может кто знает как ее решить? Я делаю это на локальном сервере, везде размер в php.ini увеличил.

Comment: Вы хотите загрузить файл размером 408Мб, хотя у вас разрешение стоит только на 100Мб в post-запросе.

Comment: а как его увеличить?
там даже файл не прописан где ошибка

Comment: В php.ini переменные: `upload_max_filesize`, `post_max_size` и вероятно `memory_limit`.

Comment: как вас тут поблагодарить? =DD